# How many rectangles, whose boundary equals or exceeds that of a $3{\times}3$ square, can fit into a $9{\times}9$ square.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I want to know how many rectangles can fit inside a $9$ by $9$ square.

However, I want to exclude any rectangles that are not greater than or equal to a $3$ by $3$ square.

By this, I mean excluding rectangles such as $(2*3),(3*2),(3*1),(3*1),(2*2)$...and so on because the are not equal to, or can be fully surrounded by, a $3*3$ square.

I have arrived at a figure of $784$ by visualizing the problem and crunching the numbers, but I would like a sounder theoretical approach that makes sense.

Comment: $9$ can't fit at once without overlap. And there are $36$ different rectangles that can fit (fewer if you believe that $6\times4$ is the same as $4\times6$). Are you asking about the _number of ways to tile_ the $9\times9$ square?

Comment: Firstly, your question ("not equal to, or cannot be fully surrounded by..." -- although I assume that you mean "can" instead of "cannot") disagrees with your title ("whose boundary equals or exceeds..."). Please tell us which one you mean! Secondly, your figure of $784$ is so far off that I wonder whether you have made some even more egregious error in the statement of your question. This question will be pounced on by the roving question-closers unless you tidy it up.

Comment: I corrected the mistake you pointed out. Basically, I want to count all the rectangles that fit inside the square. But those rectangles must either be a 3*3 square or be a rectangle that fully contains a 3*3 square.

Comment: I'd improve the wording for clarity.  My guess is that you *count* two rectangles as different if their heights OR their widths are different,  but you listed "(3*1)" twice for no apparent reason.  The other suggestion would be to describe the rectangles you want to count as those that fit inside a $9\times 9$ frame but not inside a $3\times 3$ frame (possibly excepting the $3\times 3$ square itself, though this exception will only affect the count by one).

Comment: (1) I assume two different $5\times 6$ rectangles, at different positions inside the $9 \times 9$ grid, are counted as distinct, right?  (2) In your count, do you want to include or exclude e.g. $7 \times 1$ rectangles?  Such a rectangle can neither enclose, nor be enclosed by, any $3 \times 3$ rectangle.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct - I will check answer asap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer assumes:

- Two different e.g. $5 \times 6$ rectangles at different positions (within the $9 \times 9$ grid) are counted as distinct.
- You want to **exclude** e.g. $7 \times 2$ rectangles since such a rectangle is "not greater than" (in the sense it cannot enclose) a $3 \times 3$ square.  In other words, you want to count $m \times n$ rectangles where $m \ge 3$ and $n \ge 3$.

Here is a way to count the above without exhaustive listing.

The $9\times 9$ grid of $81$ squares has $10$ vertical lines and $10$ horizontal lines, and a rectangle is defined by a pair of vertical lines and a pair of horizontal lines.

The number of ways to choose the pair of horizontal lines is ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ if you ignore the size constraint.  However, if you require $m \ge 3$, then you must exclude pairs which are one square apart ($9$ such pairs) or two squares apart ($8$ such pairs).  So the number of pairs satisfying $m \ge 3$ is $45 - 9 - 8 = 28$

Similarly the number of pairs of vertical lines satisfying $n \ge 3$ is also $28$.

Thus the number of valid rectangles is $28^2 = 784$.

Comment: Interesting approach. But should it be 9 pairs of horizontal lines that are in the same horizontal position, and 8 that are one apart?

Comment: I'm choosing the lines, i.e the boundaries of the rectangles.  So when $m=1$, the two horiz lines are one square apart, and they are $(j,j+1)$ and there are $9$ such pairs among the $10$ horiz lines.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it before reading Antkam's much better solution was:

A 3*3 cell in the top right has 1 position + 6 positions to the right. (7 total)

A 3*4 cell in the top right has 1 position + 5 positions to the right. (6 total)

A 3*5 cell in the top right has 1 position + 4 positions to the right. (5 total)

A 3*6 cell in the top right has 1 position + 3 positions to the right. (4 total)

A 3*7 cell in the top right has 1 position + 2 positions to the right. (3 total)

A 3*8 cell in the top right has 1 position + 1 positions to the right. (2 total)

A 3*9 cell in the top right has 1 position + 0 positions to the right. (1 total)

This means we have (7+6+5+4+3+2+1) = 28 rectangles in the top three rows alone.

Now repeat the process on the first three columns for another 28 rectangles.

Then there must be 28*28 total rectangles formed by the intersection of these two groups of rectangles along the top and left hand side.

Comment: your method is very similar to mine, actually, but i suppose my writeup is a little cleaner.  my ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ equals $9 + 8 + 7 + \dots + 1$, so when i subtract $45 - 9 - 8$ i get your $7 + 6 + \dots + 1$.